# Find the width of an image that is part of an array generated by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I come from a Flash background (remember Flash :) but am pretty new to JS so be gentle.

I am building a carousel around a simple ul in which each li is an image.
I have an array of all the images in the list that I get using `var list = $('#carousel li img');`

If I examine `list[0]` in the console I see it is an `HTMLImageElement` and has both a width and clientWidth listed as 74 but if I try to get that width in my script `(list[0].width, list[0].clientWidth, $(list[0]).width() etc)` I just keep getting 0.

If I specify the width in the `img` tag then I get it ok but that just seems like extra typing unless there is a good argument for including it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the image before you can acces its dimensions.

Check out an image element's `load` event. Note that it can be difficult to get working with already cached images.

You can get around that by always dealing with a new `img` element (`new Image` will create one).

Comment: I am using the JQuery 'ready()' method which I thought only fired after all images are loaded? Also, does the fact that I can trace out the img details in the console not mean that it must already be loaded?

Comment: @popClingwrap `ready()` waits for `DOMContentLoaded` or its equivalent. The `load` event of `window` is fired when all images (among other things) have downloaded.

Comment: I see. Think I read the documentation wrong :s. It seems to work fine using 'load' so I will have a play around with that. Always something new to learn :)